# Change turtlebot initial position in gazebo ros

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When launching roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch,   turtlebot initial position is always at the center (0,0,0).
How can I change this initial position? I want for example the turtleot to be at (5,0, 0) in my map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339163/change-turtlebot-initial-position-in-gazebo-ros/) by [kiko453](https://answers.ros.org/users/45196/kiko453/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The position of the robot is determined when calling the node `spawn_model` from the package `gazebo_ros`. This node is called at the line `<include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/includes/$(arg base).launch.xml">`. It will call the launch file `kobuki.launch.xml`. In this file you have :

```
  <!-- Gazebo model spawner -->
  <node name="spawn_turtlebot_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
        args="$(optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE) -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model turtlebot"/>
```

Your solution is to create a new launch file similar to turtlebot_world.launch and instead of using the include to kobuki.launch.xml copy the content direclty in your launch file and remove the argument $(optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE) to set your pose, using the arguments `-x`, `-y`, `-Y` (for yaw) like this :

```
  <!-- Gazebo model spawner -->
  <node name="spawn_turtlebot_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
        args="-x 5 -y 0 -Y 0 -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model turtlebot"/>
```

Or if you don't want to change anything you can directly set the envirronment variable `ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE` to the desired arguments :

```
export ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE="-x 5 -y 0 -Y 0"
```

Note that after executing this you have to use roslaunch in the same terminal.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kiko453](https://answers.ros.org/users/45196/kiko453/) on 2019-12-04**:
Hi many thanks. The first soplution worked fine, but now the origin of my robot in rviz does match anymore with the origin in gazebo. in the my_map.yaml file there is a field origin: [12.2, -12.2, 0.0]. How do I have to change it such the position match with the one I set in kobuki.launch.xml.  In other what coordinate transformation do I have to apply?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-12-06**:
That would be related to the AMCL configration, there are the parameters `initial_pose_x`, `initial_pose_y` and `initial_pose_a`, you just need to set them at the same values as the parameters of `spawn_model`.